# Unable to pause activity - nullpointerexception

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

This is caused from a SherlockListFragment (within a TabSwipe) and an AsyncTask doInBackground.

Clicking on a list item starts generating a big parcelable item which, when finished, should move to a new activity (outside of the TabSwipe container), passing the parcelable as a Bundle.

Here is the Async code:

```
public class BackgroundSetUpReportData extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, PainReport_Holder> {

    // declare the dialog
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // show the dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog
                .setMessage("Building Summary:\nThis may take some time.\nPlease wait...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected PainReport_Holder doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        DataLayer d = new DataLayer(getActivity().getBaseContext());

        //lots of adding to the PRH class
        return PRH;
    }

    // update the progress dialog
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    // show the data
    protected void onPostExecute(PainReport_Holder result) {
        // hide the dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        moveToActivity();
    }

}

public void moveToActivity() {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("SummaryData", PRH);
    b.putString("fromDate", fromDate);
    b.putString("toDate", toDate);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), my_new.class);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The overall class is:

```
public class myClassFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
```

This worked perfectly before moving to fragments, and still works ok, until we get to the startActivity(i) line of moveToActivity(); where it throws this error:

```
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {[app]/[app].[class]}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1037)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1181)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
05-01 23:41:39.906: E/AndroidRuntime(25684):    ... 12 more
```

Other research I have done has suggested null entries in the data being passed, but I have checked the PRH class in debug, and there are no nulls within it.

**UPDATE**

I have stepped through the AsyncTask thread, and it appears to be throwing a ClassNotFound exception at:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), my_new.class);
```

Where the 'not found' class is my_new.class, which definitely exists. Indeed, if I add

```
getActivity().finish();
```

before

```
startActivity(i);
```

then it works ok, but the calling activity is no longer in the back stack.

To clarify; the parent is

```
public class myTabsActivity extends TabSwipeActivity {
```

TabSwipeActivity is

```
public abstract class TabSwipeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
```

and the Fragment I am dealing with is

```
public class myClassFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
```

Am I missing an Implements from the Fragment maybe?

Comment: Can You post full code of this activity and fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I was getting NLP in AsyncTask in fragment once.
I don't remember if issue was exactly same but I solved it by getting reference to application context in onPreExecute

```
/* ... */
Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    /* ... */
    ctx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    /* ... */
}
```

and using it where needed instead of getActivity() like to create intent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I did some further digging and have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related with `getActivity()` inside `moveToActivity()` method. Perhaps you should use `getParent()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` or anything else.
I think `getActivity()` retuns null while using Fragments.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I did some further digging and have updated my question accordingly.